# how to loop a collections inside a database and pull element from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to extract data from the collection that is in my database, by looping, but without success.
can anyone know why i had this error?
.............................................................................

```
var express= require("express");
    app= express();

var blogPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   image: String,
   description: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("blogPost", blogPostSchema);

var blogPost = require("./models/blogPost");

//INDEX - show all blogPosts
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    // Get all blogPost from DB
    blogPost.find({}, function(err, allBlogPosts){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
          res.render("/",{blogposts:allBlogPosts});
       }
    });
});

<% blogposts.find().forEach(function(blogPost){ %>

<img src="<%= blogPost.image %>" alt="image">

<% }); %>

 TypeError: /workspace/BeProgrammer/views/index.ejs:21
    19|     
    20|     
 >> 21|     <% blogPost.find().forEach(function(blogPost){ %>
    22|         <section class="blog-list px-3 py-5 p-md-5">
blogPost.find(...).forEach is not a function
```

Comment: Looks like `blogPost.find()` is not returning array of data
Can you do console of `allBlogPosts` and show us to have clarity on your data

Comment: `blogposts.find().forEach` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: *"why I had this error"* ... you didn't mention what specific error is or specifically what is and what isn't working or provide any debugging details at all. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]